# After I convert JAR file to EXE, program throws exception

Tags: java, jar, exe

i have .java file. It runs perfectly. I convert it to .jar file. Then i try to convert it to .exe file using program named "exe4j", and successfully converted. But, when i open this .exe file there is an error message:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
     at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
     at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
     at penghitung.persentase(programguru.java:27)
     at programguru.main(programguru.java:361)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
     at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
```

What is the meaning? I'm confused because the .java file runs perfectly.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class penghitung
{
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int banyak, nilai, jumlah1, jumlah2, jumlah3, jumlah4, a, b, c, d, e, f, aa, bb, cc, dd, rata7;
long pengetahuan;
double numerik, rata1, rata2, rata3, rata4, rata5, rata6;
String pers, absen, predikat, prak, coba;

public void persentase()
{
    System.out.print("\n           *************************************");
    System.out.print("\n           ************START PROGRAM************");
    System.out.print("\n           *************************************");

    System.out.print("\n\nDEFAULT : ");
    System.out.print("\n  Tugas Sekolah  : 10 %");
    System.out.print("\n  Tugas Rumah    : 10 %");
    System.out.print("\n  Ulangan Harian : 20 %");
    System.out.print("\n  UTS            : 25 %");
    System.out.print("\n  UAS            : 30 %");
    System.out.print("\n  Keaktifan      : 5%");

    System.out.print("\n\nApakah anda ingin mengganti persentase tiap kategori? (Y/T) : ");
    pers = input.next();

    a = 10;
    b = 10;
    c = 20;
    d = 25;
    e = 30;
    f = 5;

    if (pers.equals("Y") || pers.equals("y"))
    {
        System.out.print("\n(Dalam persen)");
        System.out.print("\n  Tugas Sekolah  : ");
        a = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        System.out.print("  Tugas Rumah    : ");
        b = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        System.out.print("  Ulangan Harian : ");
        c = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        System.out.print("  UTS            : ");
        d = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        System.out.print("  UAS            : ");
        e = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        System.out.print("  Keaktifan      : ");
        f = Integer.parseInt(input.next()); 
    }

    System.out.print("\nBanyak nilai Tugas Sekolah  : ");
    aa = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
    System.out.print("Banyak nilai Tugas Rumah    : ");
    bb = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
    System.out.print("Banyak nilai Ulangan Harian : ");
    cc = Integer.parseInt(input.next());

    System.out.print("\nApakah ada nilai Praktikum? (Y/T) : ");
    prak = input.next();
    if (prak.equals("Y") || prak.equals("y"))
    {   System.out.print("Banyak nilai Praktikum : ");
        dd = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
    }
}   

public void absen()
{
    System.out.print("\n----------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.print("\nNomor absen murid : ");
    absen = input.next();
    try 
    {
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter("Data Nilai.txt", true);
        out.write("\r\n#################### NOMOR ABSEN MURID : "+ absen + "\r\n");
        out.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void tugasSekolah()
{
    System.out.print("\nTUGAS SEKOLAH\n");
    try 
    {
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter("Data Nilai.txt", true);
        out.write("\r\nTUGAS SEKOLAH\r\n");

        for (int i = 1; i <= aa; i++)
        {
            if(aa==1)
            {
                System.out.print("  Nilai : ");
                out.write("  Nilai = " + nilai + "\r\n");
                nilai = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
            }
            else 
            {   
                System.out.print("  Nilai ke-" +i+ " : ");
                nilai = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
                out.write("  Nilai ke-" +i+ " = " + nilai + "\r\n");
            }
            jumlah1 += nilai;
            rata1 = jumlah1 / aa * a / 100;   
        }
            out.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void tugasRumah()
{
    System.out.print("\nTUGAS RUMAH\n");
    try 
    {
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter("Data Nilai.txt", true);
        out.write("\r\nTUGAS RUMAH\r\n");

        for (int i=1; i<=bb; i++)
        {
            if(bb==1)
            {
                System.out.print("  Nilai : ");
                out.write("  Nilai = " + nilai + "\r\n");
                nilai = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.print("  Nilai ke-" +i+ " : ");
                nilai = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
                out.write("  Nilai ke-" +i+ " = " + nilai + "\r\n");
            }
            jumlah2 += nilai;
            rata2 = jumlah2 / bb * b / 100;
        }
            out.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}

public void ulanganHarian()
{
    System.out.print("\nULANGAN HARIAN\n");
    try 
    {
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter("Data Nilai.txt", true);
        out.write("\r\nULANGAN HARIAN\r\n");

        for (int i=1; i<=cc; i++)
        {
            if(cc==1)
            {
                System.out.print("  Nilai : ");
                out.write("  Nilai = " + nilai + "\r\n");
                nilai = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.print("  Nilai ke-" +i+ " : ");
                nilai = Integer.parseInt(input.next()); 
                out.write("  Nilai ke-" +i+ " = " + nilai + "\r\n");
            }
            jumlah3 += nilai;
            rata3 = jumlah3 / cc * c / 100;
        }
            out.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}

public void uts()
{
    System.out.print("\nUTS\n");
    System.out.print(" Nilai : ");
    nilai = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
    rata4 = nilai * d / 100;
    try 
    {
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter("Data Nilai.txt", true);
        out.write("\r\nUTS\r\n");
        out.write("  Nilai = " + nilai + "\r\n");
        out.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}

public void uas()
{
    System.out.print("\nUAS\n");
    System.out.print(" Nilai : ");
    nilai = Integer.parseInt(input.next()); 
    rata5 = nilai * e / 100;
    try 
    {
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter("Data Nilai.txt", true);
        out.write("\r\nUAS\r\n");
        out.write("  Nilai = " + nilai + "\r\n");
        out.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}

public void keaktifan()
{
    System.out.print("\nKEAKTIFAN\n");
    System.out.print(" Nilai : ");
    nilai = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
    rata6 = nilai * f / 100;
    try 
    {
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter("Data Nilai.txt", true);
        out.write("\r\nKEAKTIFAN\r\n");
        out.write("  Nilai = " + nilai + "\r\n");
        out.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}   

public void praktikum()
{
    if (prak.equals("Y") || prak.equals("y"))
    {
        System.out.print("\nPRAKTIKUM\n");
        try 
        {
            FileWriter out = new FileWriter("Data Nilai.txt", true);
            out.write("\r\nPRAKTIKUM\r\n");

            for (int i=1; i<=dd; i++)
            {
                if(dd==1)
                {
                    System.out.print("  Nilai : ");
                    out.write("  Nilai = " + nilai + "\r\n");
                    nilai = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
                }
                else 
                {
                    System.out.print(" Nilai ke-" +i+ " : ");
                    nilai = Integer.parseInt(input.next()); 
                    out.write("  Nilai ke-" +i+ " = " + nilai + "\r\n");
                }
                jumlah4 += nilai;
                rata7 = Math.round(jumlah4 / dd);
            }
                out.write("\r\n>>> NILAI PRAKTIK: " +rata7);
                out.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        System.out.print("\n\n***NILAI PRAKTIK***     : "+rata7);

    }
}   

public void pengetahuan()
{
    System.out.print("\n***NILAI PENGETAHUAN*** : ");
    pengetahuan = Math.round(rata1 + rata2 + rata3 + rata4 + rata5 + rata6);
    System.out.print(pengetahuan);
    try 
    {
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter("Data Nilai.txt", true);
        out.write("\r\n>>> NILAI PENGETAHUAN: " +pengetahuan);
        out.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}

public void predikat()
{
    if(pengetahuan > 75)
    {
        predikat = "TINGGI";
    } else if(pengetahuan == 75)
    {
        predikat = "SEDANG";
    } else
    {
        predikat = "KURANG";
    }
    System.out.print("\n***PREDIKAT***          : " +predikat);
    try 
    {
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter("Data Nilai.txt", true);
        out.write("\r\n>>> PREDIKAT : " +predikat+ "\r\n");
        out.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}

public void menu()
{
    System.out.print("\n\nTambah lagi? (Y/T) : ");
    coba = input.next();

    if (coba.equals("Y") || coba.equals("y"))
    {
        absen();
        tugasSekolah();
        tugasRumah();
        ulanganHarian();
        uts();
        uas();
        keaktifan();
        praktikum();
        pengetahuan();
        predikat();
        menu();
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.print("\n           **************************************");
        System.out.print("\n           *************EXIT PROGRAM*************");
        System.out.print("\n           **************************************");
    }
}
}


public class programguru
{
public static void main (String args[])
{       
    penghitung penghitungku = new penghitung();

    //PERSENTASE NILAI
    penghitungku.persentase();

    //NOMOR ABSEN
    penghitungku.absen();

    //NILAI TUGAS SEKOLAH
    penghitungku.tugasSekolah();

    //NILAI TUGAS RUMAH
    penghitungku.tugasRumah();

    //NILAI ULANGAN HARIAN
    penghitungku.ulanganHarian();

    //NILAI UTS
    penghitungku.uts();

    //NILAI UAS
    penghitungku.uas();

    //NILAI KEAKTIFAN
    penghitungku.keaktifan();

    //NILAI PRAKTIKUM
    penghitungku.praktikum();

    //NILAI PENGETAHUAN
    penghitungku.pengetahuan();

    //PREDIKAT
    penghitungku.predikat();

    //MENU TAMBAH
    penghitungku.menu();
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code ?

Comment: Run it with a debugger and see what happens at the problematic location.

Comment: so what goes on around this line of code: programguru.java:361 as that is the first place in you code where the exception is happening. Post some code around that area...

Comment: exe4j is a third party product software. I'm afraid we can't help you much in this.

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing here, since there is incomplete information: the error message indicates that you have an error about where you first do an "input.next();" in addition to indicating that there is "no such element".  If you are on Windows, and you are starting this executable by double-clicking an icon in a folder, then you have to figure out where "System.in" will come from.  Windows will not automatically open up a command window for you to type input; if you want that, you have to run it a different way.

Comment: You are not giving us enough information to "solve this problem".  My first try would be to open a terminal window (start button and enter 'cmd' in Windows), start the program from there, and see if it will accept the System.in input from that.  But I'm only guessing that console input is what you need -- my real point was that the error indicates there's a problem with the input in hopes that you could then research where System.in can come from in an exe4j application, and thereby solve your own problem with this hint.  I see that their manual talks about console input and output...